# Proper way to convert OLE_HANDLE to HWND in 64bit?

Tags: c++, 64-bit, 32bit-64bit, handle, ole

There is a COM class with a property which returns an `OLE_HANDLE` type (which is: `typedef UINT OLE_HANDLE`).
In the C++ code, in 32bit, this is fine: `CWnd::FromHandle( (HWND)MyComClass->HWND)`
However, in 64bit, this gives a warning:
`warning C4312: 'type cast': conversion from 'OLE_HANDLE' to 'HWND' of greater size`

I read all info, and basically MS left poor OLE_HANDLE as 32bit. However, it's safe to cast to 64bit, as it's only zero filled in 64bit.

So, using C-style cast / reinterpret_cast both gives this compiler warning, which I want to eliminate (without #pragma). What is the best/proper way for this?

Thanks

Comment: Maybe using `static_cast`?

Comment: If you are **certain** that the top 32 bits of an `HWND` are zero-filled (and I can't say that I am), then you can do `(HWND) (DWORD_PTR) MyComClass->HWND`.  It's not pretty, but it will fix that warning.  What `COM` class is it, anyway??

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/401812/what-is-the-proper-way-to-cast-from-an-ole-handle-to-an-hicon

Comment: @testfailedin1.08s - with static_cast it won't even compile

Comment: @PaulSanders , indeed, my bad. Although I prefer UINT_PTR, as OLE_HANDLE is anyway UINT. It's a COM server with GUI, which returns its main window HWND. About zero-fill:  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/ms810720(v=msdn.10)?redirectedfrom=MSDN  - see: USER and GDI handles are sign extended 32b values: [...] However, the actual value of the handle on the 64b platform, (i.e. the meaningful bits), fits within the lower 32b, while the upper bits just carry the sign.[...]

Comment: OK.  You should, in any case, be doing what @HansPassant recommends.  Because an `HWND` is sign-extended, the cast I suggested won't work.

Comment: @PaulSanders now I am confused. I changed to this: `CWnd::FromHandle((HWND)UIntToPtr(MyComClass->HWND))` - isn't this ok?

Comment: I think you're looking for [`LongToHandle`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/windows/win32/winprog64/the-tools)

Comment: @PaulSanders, well, `LongToHandle` expects a `long`, while `OLE_HANDLE` is `unsigned int`. There is no `UIntToHandle`. On the other hand, if you see the source: `#define LongToHandle( h )   ((HANDLE)(LONG_PTR) (h) )` and `#define UIntToPtr( ui )  ((VOID *)(UINT_PTR)((unsigned int)ui))` - they look the identical, as `typedef void *HANDLE;`

Comment: `LongToHandle`  won't mind being passed a `UINT`

Comment: And those casts are not identical.  One sign-extends and one doesn't.  You want the former.

Comment: @PaulSanders, ok I found this macro as well: `#define ULongToHandle( ul ) ((HANDLE)(ULONG_PTR) (ul) )` along with `#define LongToHandle( h )   ((HANDLE)(LONG_PTR) (h) )` . So you are saying `ULongToHandle` is not ok, even if I have a `unsigned int` variable?

Comment: Yes, that's what I'm saying.  The fact that you start off with a `UINT` is a red herring.